# How exactly is the block height defined in EOS?

Tags: blocks, irreversible, block-header

I wanna show users the confirmation height of their transactions. 
Which one is the way to go?

Latest block - transaction block

OR

Last irreversible block - transaction block
?

Comment: transaction block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#transaction-confirmation):

> **Transaction Confirmation**
>
> Typical DPOS blockchains have 100% block producer participation. A
>   transaction can be considered confirmed with 99.9% certainty after an
>   average of 0.25 seconds from time of broadcast.
>
> In addition to DPOS, EOS.IO adds asynchronous Byzantine Fault
>   Tolerance (aBFT) for faster achievement of irreversibility. The aBFT
>   algorithm provides 100% confirmation of irreversibility within 1
>   second.

Therefore, unlike in other blockchains, I would say the message should be binary: your transaction is irreversible (behind an irreversible block) or your transaction is not yet irreversible but has X confirmations (Latest block - transaction block)